# Dumping CPU Usage in Database

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to dump the System related parameters like CPU Usage, Memory Usage etc. in SQL server database through sql query or stored procedure itself?

I want to dump these system related parameters after every 3 or 5 minutes say.

Is it possible using SQL query?

Comment: Why would you do this? I'm not sure you are on the right way as it's not necessary bad when SS memory is used, don't forget about caching data, etc

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: actually I am creating Dashboard based on ReportServerDatabase. so I Just need what was CPU Usage/Memory available at that time.
I m Using SQl Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Resource Governor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx) in case you want to limit the resource used by SQL Server.
Only with SQL Server 2008 or later.

Comment: Only Enterprise edition of SQL server supports Resource Governor